# ListBox binding, new item in binded collection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I'm trying to implement MVVM patter in my app, and got problem with data binding. Everything works pretty fine, untill a new item appears in my collection binded to ListBox. ListBox is just not updating, and after I try to click on that box exceptions about ItemsControl is thrown.

MainView.xaml

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>  

<ListBox x:Name="Scripts" ItemsSource="{Binding Scripts, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedScript}"/>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{       

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public List<Script> Scripts
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public RelayCommand NewScriptCommand
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Scripts = Script.Scripts;
        NewScriptCommand = new RelayCommand(NewScript);
    }

    private void NewScript()
    {
        Script.NewScript();
        OnPropertyChanged("Scripts");
    }      

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And my Model, class Script.cs

```
public class Script
{
    private static List<Script> _scripts;

    public static List<Script> Scripts
    {
        get
        {
            if(_scripts == null)
            {
                _scripts = GetScripts();                    
            }
            return _scripts;
        }
    }

    public static void NewScript()
    {
        _scripts.Add(new Script());
    }
}
```

I was thinking about make ObservableCollection in MainViewModel, but then occurred other problem about updating that collection when `List<Script>` Scripts get new element.

Comment: Could you show the detail about the error?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source.See the inner exception for more information

Comment: Have you tried using `CollectionViewSource`?

Answer (score 1):

Replace List with ObservableCollection and everything will start working.  Not sure what "problem" you are talking about.  Remove OnPropertyChanged("Scripts").  The Scripts property has not changed...the collection has changed.  You need to raise a collection changed event which is what ObservableCollection does.